# FFMPEG Force Concat to skip corrupt files

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am currently using:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i clipstomerge.txt -vcodec copy -acodec copy mergedclips.mp4
```

This concats videos from a given directory listed in clipstomerge.txt. What I have noticed is that if there is a corrupted file the concat will fail.

How can I force concat to to skip the corrupted files?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have tried following this link: http://www.ffmpeg-archive.org/Force-concat-to-ignore-corrupt-files-td4664775.html
But I couldn't understand how to fit it into my bat file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run `ffprobe corrupt.mp4` and share the console readout.

Comment: What about concatenating one clip after another in a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)?

Comment: @Gyan I don't have a corrupted clip as an example right now, but when I get one I can test it. Is there not a simple way to clip files that are under 1bytes or anything?

Comment: @aschipfl They have to be concatenated using the txt file as it concats them in a specific order

Comment: The text file could be read by [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), so the order was preserved...

Comment: @aschipfl could you write out the code please? I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: No, I don't know `ffmpeg` well enough, so I can't. But what I'm thinking about is a loop that iterates over the list of files; in the loop body, there are two cases and the first one is chosen initially: 1. check whether the currently iterated files is corrupt and if not, copy it to a temporary file and switch to the next case for the remaining iterations; 2. the temporary file and the currently iterated one are concatenated, the result is written to another temporary file that replaces the former one only in case of success...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :validateConcatFile clipstomerge.txt 2048
if errorlevel 1 echo Failed.& exit /b 1

echo Passed.
exit /b

:validateConcatFile  concatFile  acceptableSize
if "%~1" == "" exit /b 2
if "%~2" == "" exit /b 2

rem Check each listed media file.
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims='" %%A in ("%~1") do (

    rem Check only if leading concat keyword is "file".
    if "%%~A" == "file " (

        rem The file needs to exist.
        if not exist "%%~B" (
            echo "%%~B" not exist.
            exit /b 1
        )

        rem Check byte size.
        for %%C in ("%%~B") do if %%~zC lss %~2 (
            echo "%%~B" size is %%~zC which is less than %~2.
            exit /b 1
        ) else echo "%%~B" size is %%~zC which is ok at %~2.

        rem FFprobe scan.
        ffprobe -i "%~1" > nul 2> nul || (
            echo FFprobe set errorlevel with "%%~B".
            exit /b 1
        )
    )
)
exit /b 0
```

The code covers some basic ideas to the problem of corrupt files.
As issues could vary with many concepts to detect corruption,
then you can regard this as a start as the code could be
expanded by anyone over time with more detection concepts.

Special characters used as escapes etc. may cause a file not exist
detection. Handling these characters is differcult so is not
available in this code and will return by setting `errorlevel`.

Other detections done:

- Concat listed files need to `exist` to pass.
- Listed files need to be atleast a certain size in *bytes* to pass.
- Listed files need to pass a simple ffprobe scan to pass.

In the code example, The first argument of the called label
`:validateConcatFile` is the concat file, which is `clipstomerge.txt`
and the 2nd argument is `2048`, which is the size in bytes that is
acceptable to pass.

Answer (score 0):

based on @michael_heath's answer I developed a simple if/else for shell in case anyone is interested:

p.s: variable minsize is in bytes

```
SOURCE=/path/folder/
MINSIZE=10000

for f in "$SOURCE"*.mp4; do ffprobe -i $f 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    if [ $(du -s $f | cut -f1) -ge $MINSIZE ]
        then
        echo "SUCCESS - $f"
    else
        echo "SIZE ERROR - $f"
    fi
else
    echo "FFPROBE ERROR - $f"
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I want to create a timelapse video from a file list from my DVR. Sometimes it happens that a single file from 50GB files is corrupt. for example, 5 seconds from the file are missing. Ok, I don't care about these 5 seconds (they won't even be noticed on the timelapse). However, when the problematic video is found, concat just stops and does not continue with remaining files - I have to do it manually. 

Playing the video with VLC or ffplay, or even re-encoding the file just skips the problematic 5 seconds and continues. ffprobe does not detect problems in the file